# php multi byte strings regex

Tags: php, utf-8

We have a regex to strip out non alpha numeric characters except for '#', '&' and '-'. Here is what it looks like:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9#&-*]/', '', strtolower($title));
```

Now we need to support traditional Chinese strings and the above function won't work. How can I implement similar functionality for traditional Chinese.

Thanks,

Comment: So which Chinese characters are "alpha numeric"?

Answer (score 3):

Use `u` modifier:

```
preg_replace(`/[^a-zA-Z0-9#&-*诶]/u`, '', $string);
```

By the way, don't use `strtolower()`, because it will break your string. Use `mb_strtolower()`:

```
mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mb_ereg_replace() instead of preg_replace()? That might do the trick.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php

Comment: ereg should be avoided in general, even if this particular one's in the mb_ section and not marked as deprecated. preg's the standard regex interface in PHP now, and ereg itself will vanish some day.

Comment: There is no preg_replace in the mb_-section though, which is why I suggested the ereg from there.